# fadeToggle() first show the element then fadeIn and Out

Tags: jquery, fadein, setinterval, fadeout

Hi I have this code that cycle over a prededeterminated time in this way:

```
var array = [
    "tip 01",
    "tip 02",
    "tip 03",
    "Tip 04",
    "Tip 05",
];
var i = 1;
var pippo = $("#div");

setInterval(function() {            
     pippo
        .fadeToggle()
        .html(array[i]);
        i++;
if (i == array.length){i=0;}

    }, 7000);
```

so the content of the div will be a cell of the array. as you can see to this #div is applied a fadeToggle effect so if the #div is visible will be faded Out and viceversa.

The problem is that the animation doesn't work propely.

When the animation start it's like first is shownd the #div content (with no animation) than is faded out and than faded in...

I'd like that the #div it's just fade in and out.

A think that I've notice is that It's like the cycle loops two times in the 7 seconds. 
because if I write:

```
setInterval(function() {            
     pippo
        .fadeIn()
        .html(array[i])
        .fadeOut();
        i++;
if (i == array.length){i=0;}

    }, 7000);
```

the fading effect is activated two times like: fade in fade out fade in fade out fade in. and than again when the 7 seconds are passed.

How I can make this animation smooth?
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Create a jsfiddle to help people help you..

Comment: sorry @Nelson you're right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to fadeOut changeHTML fadeIn you can do this

```
var array = [
"tip 01",
"tip 02",
"tip 03",
"Tip 04",
"Tip 05",
];
var i = 0;
var pippo = $("#div");
function f(){
    pippo.fadeOut(function(){
        pippo.html(array[i]).fadeIn(function(){
            i++;
            if (i == array.length){i=0;}
            setTimeout(f, 7000);
        });
    });
}
setTimeout(f, 7000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDVWd/1/)

Comment: thanks a lot it works like a charm...but can you explain me a bit the code? can i manipulate the fadeIn easing and animation timing with "slow" or "fast" or in millisecond?

Comment: yes you can add slow, fast or millisecond on `pippo.fadeOut('slow',function` or `pippo.html(array[i]).fadeIn('fast',function()`

Answer (score 1):

Possible, fadeToggle function actions overlap, try this:

```
var array = [
    "tip 01",
    "tip 02",
    "tip 03",
    "Tip 04",
    "Tip 05",
];
var i = 1;
var pippo = $("#div");

function fader() {            
    pippo.fadeToggle(function(){
        i++;
        if (i == array.length){i=0;}
        setTimeout(fader, 7000) 
    }).html(array[i]);
}
```